# Python string split only on numbers preceded or followed by a space

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string that I would like to split into a list. I'm trying to figure out how to split it on digits that are preceded and followed by a space.

I have tried the following and it is almost what I need.

```
\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+
```

---

#### Attempt

```
import re

# Find the numeric values: 
tmplist = re.split(r'\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+', 'Dual 425mm AutoCannon 25') 


# Print the list
print(tmplist)
```

This is the outcome:

```
['Dual', '425mm AutoCannon', '25']
```

This is the desired outcome:

```
['Dual 425mm AutoCannon', '25']
```

Comment: What is the rule here? It seems you want to match whitespace chars only before a whole word number, try `r"\s+(?=\d+\b)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to match a space and use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right are 1+ digits which after that are non followed by a non whitespace char:

```
\s(?=\d+(?!\S))
```

- `\s` Whitespace char
- `(?=` positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not

    - `\S` Match non whitespace char
  - `)` Close negative lookahead
- Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bZGP5B/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Q6DmVD)

Your code could look like:

```
import re
tmplist = re.split(r'\s(?=\d+(?!\S))', 'Dual 425mm AutoCannon 25') 
print(tmplist)
```

Result

```
['Dual 425mm AutoCannon', '25']
```

See a [regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cs(%3F%3D%5Cd%2B(%3F!%5CS))) visual

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. So is the (?!\S) like a "nested"  lookahead for lack of a better word?

Comment: It is a nested lookahead which asserts after matching 1+ digits what is directly after that is not a non whitespace character.

Comment: @KC. I have added a visual for some extra clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the prettiest, but since regex can be difficult to read at times or go back and remember why you did what you did, here's a function that can accomplish what you're trying to do. I extended your text a little bit more just to make sure it kept working.

```
def split_on_number(text):

    final = [text.split()[0]]  # Autoload the first item
    for i in text.split()[1:]: # Ignore the first item

        try:
            #Try to convert it to a float
            float(i)           

        except ValueError: 
            # if there's an issue, append to last item
            final[-1] = " ".join([final[-1], i]) 

        else:
            # if you can covnert to a float, then append it
            final.append(i)    

    return final

print(split_on_number('Dual 425mm AutoCannon 25 with another 4 items'))
# ['Dual 425mm AutoCannon', '25 with another', '4 items']
```